# Why creating marker fails while aruco module is defined in opencv?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, aruco

I am trying to generate marker dictionary in opencv c++, the aruco module is integrated in visual studio. While i try to run the aruco example i get no output, also no errors. Even when creating a dictionary through the following line: `Ptr<aruco::Dictionary> markerDict = aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(aruco::PREDEFINED_DICTIONARY_NAME::DICT_4X4_50);`

I get the following error:

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const cv::aruco::Dictionary' to 'cv::Ptr'

Any help?

Comment: I've seen some similar problems with the answer to use core/contrib 3.2.0. I don't know if that's the solution but you can try

Comment: @cplusogl I am using opencv 3.1 , also contrib 3.1. Do you mean to try 3.2 version?

Comment: Change your declaration to `auto markerDict = ...`. If that compiles, your variable type is wrong (maybe `Ptr<const aruco::Dictionary>` works, although the doc says your type should be fine). If it doesn't compile you may have forgotten to include all necessary headers.

Comment: @MahaMohy Yes core/contrib 3.2, you can give it a try if that's no problem

Comment: @Timo , Thank you auto worked but another error appears saying "cannot open file 'opencv_aruco310d.lib' "

Comment: @cplusogl, Thanks i will give a try.

Comment: @MahaMohy Try building it in release mode, instead of debug

Comment: Well then the compiler can't find your lib file, you should reference it properly.

Comment: @Timo, many thanks i referenced it well and it worked.